# Vba selenium dependency injection of one instance of chromedriver

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dependency-injection

I am scraping webpage via Selenium in VBA.
What is current problem of mine? - I "refactored" my code, by creating functions to scrape each let's say segment of data. But in every call of function it creates new instance of chrome. I used getObject("Selenium.Webdriver") instead of New ChromeDriver code line. It does not help. Instead it created even without quitting after scrape ends. Then I took Dim driver As Webdriver to out of Subprocedure declaration. Also does not help.

I looked for it on web. It seems like I misuse in every function start "chrome", url (but without it page does not open) and I think I need to use driver.ExecuteScript "window.focus():" but do not know how? Do i need to get rid of start or get methods?

```
Public Function brngData_001(L_url As String, i As Integer, j As Integer) As String

    Dim driver As WebDriver
        Set driver = GetObject("Selenium.WebDriver") 'New ChromeDriver
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("main")
    
        With driver
'            .Start "chrome", L_url
'            .Get "/"
            .ExecuteScript "window.focus();"
            .Wait 1000
            
        Set elementsClass = .FindElementsByClass("base-search-card__info")
        
'On Error GoTo here:

                    ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = elementsClass(j).FindElementByCss("h3").Text
                    ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = elementsClass(j).FindElementByCss("h4").Text
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = elementsClass(j).FindElementByCss("span").Text
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = elementsClass(j).FindElementByCss("time").Text

        End With
        
'Exit Function
'here:
'Debug.Print Err.Description, Now(), Err.Number
'driver.GoBack 'Index was outside the bounds of the array. -2146233080
'Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: How can we really help with 2 lines of code?  It would help to show us an example of how you refactored your code.

Comment: I 've edited and added code

Comment: You could pass `driver` into your function if you already have an instance in the calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the result by commenting out

```
driver.Start "chrome", url
driver.get "/"
```

code snippets in functions that are called. So my code has only one .start, get method.

For getting Selenium Webdriver instance that is created (that is already in use) I use

```
driver.getObject("Selenium.WebDriver")
```